# Get the union of 2 series having different root items in Websphere TX

Tags: websphere, wtx

Here is a sample of my problem. I have the following typetree :

```
Root
 |-Text(item)
 |-Texts(group, delimited, literal separator=<NEXT>, components=Text[1:s])
```

I have 3 cards :

```
serie1 (type=Texts), rule =clone("test", 3)
serie2 (type=Texts), rule =clone("test", 3) 
union (type=Texts), rule =?
```

How can I get the union to contain both the values from serie1 and serie2 ?

If possible not using a RUN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to modify your type tree like this:

```
Root
 |-Text(item)
 |-Texts(group, delimited, literal separator=<NEXT>, components=Text[1:s])
 |-Texts(group, delimited, literal separator=<NEXT>, components=Text[0:s])
```

This way you can copy directly the data to the output and you should not have problems reading a file with that type tree either.

Regards,
B.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I haven't worked with WTX in years I am unable to say if your answer would actually work or not. I will validate it in case, hopefully it will help someone who will leave a message about it here :)